# Change decimal separator to comma using commerce-order:commerce-order-total:amount_decimal

Tags: commerce, tokens

I use D7 in a commerce website. I am setting up an email that will be sent to the user who just made an order.
In this mail, the token [commerce-order:commerce_order_total] is used to display subtotal, vat, shipping and total.

[image: Screenshot with a test order]

As you can see in the screenshot i use EURO as currency where the decimal separator is comma ','. (The translation is in Greek). So far so good.
After some information in the email, i need to indicate the exact amount that should be paid. I tried with token [commerce-order:commerce-order-total:amount_decimal] but as you can see the decimal separator is the dot and not the comma...

Is it something i can do to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with hook_commerce_currency_info_alter(). Please do refer the discussion in this thread, you will get an idea. 
[Comma as decimal point](https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/520/comma-decimal-point)